# What does 'Function definition too long' mean in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I was creating a stored procedure and I stumbled with this issue.
What are snowflake limits for stored procedures in Javascript?

Comment: Can you place code or issue which you encountered ..that helps people to take a look and help .Any add specifics on limitations to address.

Comment: Sorry, this issue was caused by trying to create a big stored procedure. In general in snowflake the syntax is `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FOO() RETURNS STRING LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT AS $$ xxxx $$`; My question is about what are the actual limits.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did several tests and I got some confusing results.

I mostly started getting this error when the total length of the procedure definition was over 800000 characters.
The maximum I got was 810000. My assumption is that there is some limitation based on compress size.

But until know all I can say is:

- There is a limit for the size of your procs
- The limit is something over 780K

If you reach that limit, it will be better if you split your proc.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, the Snowflake manual [says](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/javascript/udf-javascript-introduction.html#code-size)

> Snowflake limits the maximum size of the JavaScript source code in the body of a JavaScript UDF. Snowflake recommends limiting the size to 100 KB. (The code is stored in a compressed form, and the exact limit depends on the compressibility of the code.)

So it is not the number of lines of code, but the total code size after compression. Removing "uncompressible" parts of your code (e.g. comments), or running your code thru a JavaScript minimizer is likely the best way to keep under the limit until/unless Snowflake lift the limit in some future release.

For the record, I've found the limit to be closer to **46 KB** of  JavaScript code rather than the stated 100 KB.

If you hit this limit yourself, then feel free to let Snowflake know and encourage them to raise it :-)

Answer (score 0):

At one point I was implementing a Javascript UDF to unpack base64 data, and my naïve JS got this error, in the end I rewrote the JS to build more dense table data, and sucked all the data into 24K

of which each row looked something like:

```
1054:{type:10,scale:1},1055:{type:10,scale:1},1056:{type:10,scale:1},1057:{type:10,scale:1},1058:{type:10,scale:1},1059:{type:10,scale:1},1060:{type:10,scale:1},1061:{type:10,scale:1},1062:{type:10,scale:1},1063:{type:10,scale:1},1064:{type:10,scale:1},1065:{type:10,scale:1},1066:{type:10,scale:1},1067:{type:3,scale:1},1068:{type:5,scale:0.05},1069:{type:10,scale:1},1070:{type:10,scale:1},1071:{type:10,scale:1},1072:{type:10,scale:1},1073:{type:10,scale:1},1074:{type:10,scale:1},1075:{type:10,scale:1},1076:{type:10,scale:1},1077:{type:10,scale:1},1078:{type:5,scale:1},1079:{type:10,scale:1},1080:{type:10,scale:1},1081:{type:5,scale:1},1082:{type:4,scale:0.01},1083:{type:4,scale:0.01},1085:{type:5,scale:1},1086:{type:5,scale:1},1087:{type:5,scale:1},1088:{type:5,scale:1},1089:{type:5,scale:1},1090:{type:5,scale:1},1091:{type:5,scale:1},1092:{type:5,scale:1},1093:{type:5,scale:1},1094:{type:5,scale:1},1095:{type:3,scale:1},1096:{type:5,scale:1},1097:{type:5,scale:1},1098:{type:5,scale:1},1099:{type:10,scale:1},1100:{type:10,scale:1},4089:{type:10,scale:1},4090:{type:4,scale:0.05},4091:{type:1,scale:1},4092:{type:2,scale:1},4093:{type:5,scale:0.5},4094:{type:10,scale:1},8001:{type:3,scale:0.1},8002:{type:3,scale:0.1},8003:{type:3,scale:0.1},8004:{type:3,scale:0.1},8005:{type:3,scale:0.1},
```

and now that I think about it, I could have saved a lot by `scale` and `type` being `s` and `t` (7.5K it seems)

anyways, the whole file that was small enough was 29K.

Depending if your SP is data heave or code heavy, I found I got a really good performance improvement, by rely of the fact that state is persisted (mostly) across calls to a JS function, thus wrapped the two large data tables I was using like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unpack_base64_data(s string)
  RETURNS variant
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS '
if (typeof revLookup === "undefined") {  
  revLookup = {"43":62,"45":62,"....
}
```

thus if the object existed, the object was not rebuilt.

so maybe not the exact answer you where looking for, but a data point of what a known "worked" was, and some ideas how to fit in.

which imply using some form of min/webpack on the js might be of value also.

Comment: Thanks. This is a great tip! I will do some research about it. It looks handy for several scenarios

Answer (score 0):

While I can’t see it explicitly documented anywhere, there is a 16MB limit on most (all?) objects in Snowflake so that probably includes SP definitions as well.

For example, the PROCEDURES view holds the sp definition in a TEXT field and these are limited to 16MB

Comment: Thanks @Nickw. I am aware of the 16MB limit, but in this case the limitation is far less, at least according to my tests